# Why this DOM DFS algorithm doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, dom, depth-first-search

I tried the algorith below to DFS the DOM tree but it doesn't work! It can just check the first path in the DOM tree. WHY?!

```
function DFS(P) // (ScanRegion, Elem, MCF)
{
    P.Elem.setAttribute("Checked", "1");

    Children = P.Elem.querySelectorAll("*");

    for(I = 0, L = Children.length; I < L; I++)
        DFS
        (
            {
                ScanRegion : P.ScanRegion,
                Elem       : Children[I] ,
                MCF        : P.MCF
            }
        );

    return;
}

DFS
(
    {
        ScanRegion : document.body,
        Elem       : document.body,
        MCF        : "Not important in this question :D"
    }
);
```

after days of debugging I finally found out the problem. I tried the code below and understood that after the function riches to the first leaf of the DOM tree and the browser runs the first 'return' of the recursive function, the 'L' variable of the parent function loses its value and changes to '0'. I guess that it is because of variable scope problems in JS because as you know the 'L' of the child function is '0' (Because a leaf has no child :D) and I think it affects on the parent function.

here's the debugging code I tried:

```
function DFS(P) // (ScanRegion, Elem, MCF)
{
    P.Elem.setAttribute("Checked", "1");

    Children = P.Elem.querySelectorAll("*");

    L = Children.length; alert(L); // * New

    for(I = 0; I < L; I++)
        DFS
        (
            {
                ScanRegion : P.ScanRegion,
                Elem       : Children[I] ,
                MCF        : P.MCF
            }
        );

    alert(L); // * New

    return;
}

DFS
(
    {
        ScanRegion : document.body,
        Elem       : document.body,
        MCF        : "Not important in this question :D"
    }
);
```

I would be grateful if any one knows the problem or has the true code :)

Comment: Hold on, both codes don’t work, right? I’m a bit confused about what exactly doesn’t work in the second code.

Comment: The second one is just a debugging version and only has two more alerts.

Comment: Anyway thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your local variables with `var`!!  As it stands, `I` is *global*. Same with `L`. Because of that, the recursive calls mess up the parent's iteration.

Add

```
var I, L;
```

to the top of the function. (Also consider using lower-case for variable names; it's much more common in JavaScript code.)

Comment: Thank you so much, you really helped me in my project :-D

Comment: Plus, I need to use var for Children as well.

Comment: @Arvin yes I missed that one :)